# How to display multiple values in a single number field for an action on the timeline?

Tags: layout, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

How can you get something like "3.77 mi run in 30:31 April 21" displayed in a number field above the map like this example from the Developer Blog: https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/endo_agg5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In that example '3.77mi run' is the title of the object, the rest are the time and duration fields, you should be able to configure the display type in the app settings

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the object to the action type which triggers the wall post. So, for example, when you have the following:

Action : run
Object : route

Then, in the MapLayout, the following field should be filled:

Header : {route.title}

Now, you will have a clickable link like in the figure